# How to rewrite last word in C#

Tags: c#, cpu-word

How do I change or rewrite a type last word. For example: and = 和. So can some help me do this and show me how. Also how do I join on more words as I learn this language. Please help me.

Comment: go through the string class functions and will find at least one method that makes what you want.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you want to do? Replace the last word in a sentence, is that all?

Comment: To replace a word after type by the user that what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

```
string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');
words[words.Length - 1] = "newWord";
sentence = string.Join(" ", words);
```